# LINQ Aggregate vs. nested foreach

Tags: linq, aggregate

I am trying to achieve:

```
foreach (ScheduleItem s in ScheduleItems)
{
    foreach (IScheduleModule m in s.ScheduleModules)
    {
        yield return m;
    }
}
```

using LINQ aggregate and I do not understand why

```
return ScheduleItems.Aggregate(new Collection<IScheduleModule>(), (x, o) => x.Union(o.ScheduleModules) as Collection<IScheduleModule>);
```

returns null.

I have no issue using the nested foreach but my instinct was to use aggregate and I don't understand why it doesn't produce the same result.

Are there other approaches? What is best in terms of readability and performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be using [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) for this:

```
ScheduleItems.SelectMany(s => s.ScheduleModules)
```

That exactly matches your initial nested foreach loop. It's also equivalent to this query expression:

```
from s in ScheduleItems
from m in s.ScheduleModules
select m
```

(although that will use a slightly different form of `SelectMany`).

As for why `Aggregate` isn't working: you're calling Union which returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, but then using `as` to try to convert it to `Collection<T>`. The result of `Union` won't be a `Collection<T>`, hence the result of the `as` operator is null.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This is exactly what I was looking to do and in a much tidier fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)?  Based on your question, that sounds like what you are looking for.

```
var results = ScheduleItems.SelectMany(si => si.ScheduleModules);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is a much better solution than Aggregate (that's assuming it could be coerced into doing it)